# UI doesn't update in react js using redux toolkit + inputs error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, input, redux-toolkit

I know this is common question and something is wrong with state, but I still need help with understanding of all features of Redux and Redux-toolkit. So, in my PET project I'm trying to edit an invoice, but UI isn't updating, however it logs to the console changes which you make (here is screenshot).[image: consoles updated info]

And if I try to edit items(item name or unit costs or unit) it shows an error. [image: input error]

It's kind of 2 problems in one post, but related to the same topic :)

Now the code.

***invoice-slice.js*** file with *editInvoice* reducer where might be the problem of updating the state, but i don't know where it can be:

```
editInvoice(state) {
      const existingItem = state.invoices;
      existingItem.map((item) => {
        if (existingItem.id === item.id) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            bill_from: item.billFrom,
            bill_from_info: item.billFromInfo,
            bill_to: item.billTo,
            bill_to_info: item.billToInfo,
            invoice_num: item.invoiceNumber,
            status: item.status,
            order_date: item.order_date,
            ITEMS: [...item.ITEMS],
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },
```

***EditInvoice.js*** file:

```
import React from "react";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import classes from "./EditInvoice.module.css";

import EditInvoiceItem from "./EditInvoiceItem";

const EditInvoice = () => {
  const { invoiceId } = useParams();

  const invoices = useSelector((state) => state.invoice.invoices);

  const invoice = invoices.find((invoice) => invoice.id === invoiceId);

  return invoice ? (
    <EditInvoiceItem
      invoiceNumber={invoice.invoice_num}
      billFrom={invoice.bill_from}
      billFromInfo={invoice.bill_from_info}
      billTo={invoice.bill_to}
      billToInfo={invoice.bill_to_info}
      status={invoice.status}
      orderDate={invoice.order_date}
      items={invoice.ITEMS}
      itemName={invoice.item_name}
      unitCosts={invoice.unit_costs}
      units={invoice.units}
    />
  ) : (
    <div className={classes.centered}>Invoice Not Found.</div>
  );
};

export default EditInvoice;
```

***EditInvoiceItem.js*** file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { uiActions } from "../../store/ui-slice";

import classes from "./AddInvoiceItem.module.css";

import { useFormik } from "formik";

import Wrapper from "../../UI/Wrapper";
import Card from "../../UI/Card";
import Footer from "../../UI/Footer";
import Button from "../../UI/Button";

import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCalendar } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { faEllipsis } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { invoiceActions } from "../../store/invoice-slice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const EditInvoiceItem = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const date = new Date();

  const options = ["Pending", "Shipped", "Delivered"];

  const inputs = [{ item_name: "", unit_costs: "", unit: "" }];

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(date);
  // const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(props.orderDate || date);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(
    props.status || options[0]
  );
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(props.items || inputs);

  // console.log(props.orderDate.toJSON());

  const optionClickHandler = (value) => () => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
    dispatch(uiActions.toggleMoreOptions());
  };

  const editInvoiceHandler = (invoice) => {
    console.log(invoice);
    dispatch(
      invoiceActions.editInvoice({
        id: invoice.id,
        invoiceNumber: invoice.invoiceNumber,
        billFrom: invoice.billFrom,
        billFromInfo: invoice.billFromInfo,
        billTo: invoice.billTo,
        billToInfo: invoice.billToInfo,
        status: selectedOption,
        order_date: startDate.toLocaleDateString(),
        ITEMS: [...updateValuesOnSubmit()],
      })
    );
  };

  const formikEditInvoice = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      invoiceNumber: props.invoiceNumber,
      billFrom: props.billFrom,
      billFromInfo: props.billFromInfo,
      billTo: props.billTo,
      billToInfo: props.billToInfo,
      status: props.status,
      order_date: props.orderDate,
      item_name: props.itemName,
      unit_costs: props.unitCosts,
      units: props.units,
    },
    onSubmit: (val) => {
      editInvoiceHandler(val);
      navigate("/invoices", { replace: true });
    },
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const toggleMoreOptions = () => {
    dispatch(uiActions.toggleMoreOptions());
  };

  const showOtherOptions = useSelector(
    (state) => state.ui.selectMoreOptionsIsVisible
  );

  let counter = 1;

  const addItemHandler = () => {
    setListItems(listItems.concat({ item_name: "", unit_costs: "", unit: "" }));
  };

  const updateItemHandler = (index, inputName, value) => {
    listItems[index] = { ...listItems[index], [inputName]: value };
  };

  const updateValuesOnSubmit = () => {
    return listItems;
  };

  const navigateBack = () => {
    navigate(-1);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formikEditInvoice.handleSubmit}>
      <Wrapper isShrinked={props.isShrinked}>
        <Card>
          <div className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes["buttons-wrapper"]}>
              <button
                type="button"
                className={classes["cancel-btn"]}
                onClick={navigateBack}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
              <Button>Save</Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes["invoice-info-wrapper"]}>
              <div className={classes["invoice-info"]}>
                <h3>Invoice Info</h3>
                <input
                  placeholder="Number"
                  type="text"
                  name="invoiceNumber"
                  id="invoiceNumber"
                  onChange={formikEditInvoice.handleChange}
                  value={formikEditInvoice.values.invoiceNumber}
                  onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className={classes["right-side-column"]}>
                <div className={classes["order-status"]}>
                  <span>Order Status: </span>
                  <div className={classes.buttons}>
                    {showOtherOptions && (
                      <ul className={classes.options}>
                        {options.map((option, index) => (
                          <li onClick={optionClickHandler(option)} key={index}>
                            {option}
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    )}
                    <button type="button" className={classes.status}>
                      {selectedOption}
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className={classes.dots}
                      onClick={toggleMoreOptions}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsis} />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes["order-date"]}>
                  <span>Order Date:</span>
                  <DatePicker
                    className={classes["order-date-input"]}
                    selected={startDate}
                    onChange={(val) => setStartDate(val)}
                  />
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={faCalendar}
                    className={classes.calendar}
                  ></FontAwesomeIcon>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes["order-bills"]}>
              <div className={classes["bill-from"]}>
                <input
                  placeholder="Bill From"
                  type="text"
                  name="billFrom"
                  id="billFrom"
                  onChange={formikEditInvoice.handleChange}
                  value={formikEditInvoice.values.billFrom}
                  onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                ></input>
                <textarea
                  placeholder="Bill From Info"
                  name="billFromInfo"
                  id="billFromInfo"
                  onChange={formikEditInvoice.handleChange}
                  value={formikEditInvoice.values.billFromInfo}
                  onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div className={classes["bill-to"]}>
                <input
                  placeholder="Bill To"
                  type="text"
                  name="billTo"
                  id="billTo"
                  onChange={formikEditInvoice.handleChange}
                  value={formikEditInvoice.values.billTo}
                  onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                ></input>
                <textarea
                  placeholder="Bill To Info"
                  name="billToInfo"
                  id="billToInfo"
                  onChange={formikEditInvoice.handleChange}
                  value={formikEditInvoice.values.billToInfo}
                  onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes["table-wrapper"]}>
              <table>
                <colgroup>
                  <col className={classes.col1}></col>
                  <col className={classes.col2}></col>
                  <col className={classes.col3}></col>
                  <col className={classes.col4}></col>
                  <col className={classes.col5}></col>
                  <col className={classes.col6}></col>
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td className={classes["more-padding"]}>#</td>
                    <td>Item Name</td>
                    <td>Unit Costs</td>
                    <td>Unit</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {listItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr data-1={item} key={index}>
                      <td className={classes["more-padding"]}>{counter++}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Item Name"
                          className={classes.inputs}
                          name="itemName"
                          id="itemName"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            updateItemHandler(
                              index,
                              "item_name",
                              e.currentTarget.value
                            )
                          }
                          value={item.item_name}
                          onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                        ></input>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Unit Costs"
                          className={classes.inputs}
                          name="unitCosts"
                          id="unitCosts"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            updateItemHandler(
                              index,
                              "unit_costs",
                              e.currentTarget.value
                            )
                          }
                          value={item.unit_costs}
                          onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                        ></input>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          placeholder="Unit"
                          className={classes.inputs}
                          name="unit"
                          id="unit"
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            updateItemHandler(
                              index,
                              "unit",
                              e.currentTarget.value
                            )
                          }
                          value={item.unit}
                          onBlur={formikEditInvoice.handleBlur}
                        ></input>
                      </td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td></td>
                      {/* There should be dynamic values later */}
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div className={classes["add-item-btn"]}>
                <button
                  onClick={addItemHandler}
                  type="button"
                  className={classes["add-item-btn"]}
                >
                  Add Item
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.total}>
                <p className={classes["sub-total"]}>
                  <span>Sub Total: </span>
                  <span>$0</span>
                  {/* Dynamic value later here */}
                </p>
                <div className={classes["total-vat"]}>
                  <span>Total Vat:</span>
                  <div className={classes["total-sum"]}>
                    <span className={classes["input-wrapper"]}>
                      <input type="text" defaultValue="10"></input>
                      <span>%</span>
                    </span>
                    <span className={classes.sum}>$0</span>
                    {/* Dynamic value later here */}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className={classes["grand-total"]}>
                  <h3>Grand Total</h3>
                  <div className={classes.input}>
                    <input type="text" defaultValue="$"></input>
                    <span>0</span>
                    {/* Dynamic value later here */}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.dummy}></div>
          </div>
        </Card>
        <Footer />
      </Wrapper>
    </form>
  );
};

export default EditInvoiceItem;
```

In my project I'm using Formik to listen for input changes, but in listening to items changes I'm not using it, because i had an issue with that and one guy suggested me that code.

So, I'm facing 2 issues:

1. UI doesn't update the changes, but i can see in console that changes are made(probably the code in invoice-slice.js is wrong);
2. When i click and want to change the inputs of Item Name, Unit Costs and Unit i get an error in console and can't change anything.

Please, try helping me and explaining what can cause such problems!

P.S. here is my github repo - https://github.com/stepan-slyvka/test-project

P.P.S. and here is CodeSandbox - [image: Edit zen-pateu-p6f7bq]

Comment: I can't see any mutation happening in `editInvoice` - is this intended? The `.map` loop creates a new array that isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: @timotgl What do you mean? I don't understand. What mutation should happen in editInvoice ? And map should be assigned to something?

Comment: It's a reducer, it's supposed to mutate the state (or return a modified state, as classic reducers do) but it looks like it doesn't do that. When you use Array.map the result is typically assigned to something, otherwise you'd use .forEach or a for ... in loop.

Comment: @timotgl Okay. So, if i do like this: ` editInvoice(state) {
      const existingItem = state.invoices;
      state.invoices = existingItem.map((item) => {
        if (existingItem.id === item.id) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            ......
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    },`  It gonna work?

Comment: Yeah I mean, don't ask me, try it out :)

Comment: @timotgl Still the same) it doen't work

Comment: The reducer case does not handle an action. It can't possibly mutate the state if the edited invoice isn't there.

Comment: @timotgl So what should I do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

The main issue is that the `editInvoice` reducer function isn't consuming an `action` and its payload, so the passed updated invoice data isn't referenced, and the array mapping result isn't used.

Additionally, the `EditInvoice` component isn't passing along the invoice id to the `EditInvoiceItem` (*or `EditInvoiceItem` isn't capturing it from the path parameters. The `invoice.id` isn't populated into the form data so it's also not passed along to `editInvoiceHandler` to be dispatched to the store. This causes the array mapping to fail to find the invoice object that needs to be updated.

## Solution

EditInvoice

`EditInvoice` needs to pass `invoice.id` as a prop to `EditInvoiceItem`. *It would be quite a bit more clean and easier to maintain to simply pass the entire `invoice` object though.*

```
const EditInvoice = () => {
  const { invoiceId } = useParams();

  const invoices = useSelector((state) => state.invoice.invoices);

  const invoice = invoices.find((invoice) => invoice.id === invoiceId);

  return invoice ? (
    <EditInvoiceItem
      id={invoice.id} // <-- passed here
      invoiceNumber={invoice.invoice_num}
      billFrom={invoice.bill_from}
      billFromInfo={invoice.bill_from_info}
      billTo={invoice.bill_to}
      billToInfo={invoice.bill_to_info}
      status={invoice.status}
      orderDate={invoice.order_date}
      items={invoice.ITEMS}
      itemName={invoice.item_name}
      unitCosts={invoice.unit_costs}
      units={invoice.units}
    />
  ) : (
    <div className={classes.centered}>Invoice Not Found.</div>
  );
};
```

EditInvoiceItem

`EditInvoiceItem` should initialize the form state with the invoice id.

```
const formikEditInvoice = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    id: props.id, // <-- pass id value...
    invoiceNumber: props.invoiceNumber,
    billFrom: props.billFrom,
    billFromInfo: props.billFromInfo,
    billTo: props.billTo,
    billToInfo: props.billToInfo,
    status: props.status,
    order_date: props.orderDate,
    item_name: props.itemName,
    unit_costs: props.unitCosts,
    units: props.units,
  },
  onSubmit: (val) => {
    editInvoiceHandler(val); // <-- ...so it's passed along here
    navigate("/invoices", { replace: true });
  },
});
```

invoice-slice

The `editInvoice` case reducer should consume both the current `state` and the dispatched `action` so the payload containing the invoice data can be accessed.

```
editInvoice(state, action) {
  const { payload } = action;

  state.invoices = state.invoices.map((item) =>
    item.id === payload.id
      ? {
          ...item,
          bill_from: payload.billFrom,
          bill_from_info: payload.billFromInfo,
          bill_to: payload.billTo,
          bill_to_info: payload.billToInfo,
          invoice_num: payload.invoiceNumber,
          status: payload.status,
          order_date: payload.order_date,
          ITEMS: payload.ITEMS.slice()
        }
      : item
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ui-doesnt-update-in-react-js-using-redux-toolkit-inputs-error]

Comment: yes, it works! Thank you! Finally, i can edit my invoices :) And what about inputs(item name, unit costs and unit)? Have any idea why does it show error and crash the page? The issue is - When i click and want to change the inputs of Item Name, Unit Costs and Unit i get an error in console and can't change anything.

Comment: @StepanSlyvka Can you clarify which inputs you are referring to? Is it crashing in the sandbox I provided? Hmm, the item name, costs, and unit inputs don't appear to be editable in my sandbox code. Investigating.

Comment: @StepanSlyvka OK, the `updateItemHandler` in `EditInvoiceItem` was just mutating the state instead of updating it normally. I've updated the codesandbox from my answer.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing!!! Now everything works fine! Thank you very much! Really, I appreciate your help!